# Prove infinite series is bounded

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

If I already know $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges absolutely. And I try to prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (a_n)^2$ converges too.

Because $(a_k)^2$ is always positive, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (a_n)^2$ is nondecreasing. Therefore, one thing I left to prove is that the series is bounded.

I know the first infinite series can give me $a_n \rightarrow 0$, but Im not sure how its gonna help me with solving this problem.

Comment: Everything will be OK if $\sum a_n$ is absolutely convergent. However, there are cases where $\sum a_n$ converges but $\sum a_n^2$ does not.

Comment: My bad I have already known $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges absolutely. And I want to prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (a_n)^2$ also converges. Only only thing I need to do is try to prove $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (a_n)^2$ is bounded.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it is true unless $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ absolutely converges.

Counter example can be:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n\frac1{\sqrt n}$$

converges, whereas

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {a_n}^2=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac1{n}$$
doesn't.

---

When $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges absolutely:

As $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=0$, there exists $N$ such that
$$|a_n|<1\quad(n\ge N)$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n^2-\sum_{n=1}^{N-1} a_n^2=\sum_{n=N}^{\infty} a_n^2<\sum_{n=N}^{\infty} |a_n|<\infty$$
$$\therefore \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n^2<\infty$$

Comment: You are right. It converges absolutely. Do you know how to prove second infinite series is bounded?

Comment: I added the case where $a_n$ converges absolutely.